# Copy-Item The given path's format is not supported - Copies anyway

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to copy all pdf files from the current folder to a subdirectory called "PDFs", renaming files if they already exist. Powershell is throwing an error that the path format is not supported, but they copy anyway.

```
$pdfFolder = ".\PDFs"
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem *.pdf){

    $sourceFile = $file.Name
    $destinationFile = "$pdfFolder\$sourceFile"

    if (Test-Path $destinationFile){
        $i = 0
        While (Test-Path $destinationFile) {
            $i+= 1
            $destinationFile = "$pdfFolder\$file$i.pdf"
        }
    } else {
        New-Item -ItemType File -Path $destinationFile -Force
    }

    Copy-Item -Path $sourceFile -Destination $destinationFile -Force

}
```

I have two modified versions of this function in my program which work for .doc and .docx files, but these don't seem to be throwing up any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Solved! The .pdf extension needed to be removed for destination files.

```
$destinationFile = "$pdfFolder\$file$i.pdf"
```

Should be

```
$destinationFile = "$pdfFolder\$file$i"
```